# Querydsl Spring 3 compilation problems

Tags: java, spring, maven, querydsl

When I am trying to build my project I get "Compilation failure
[ERROR] Attempt to recreate a file for type NoteApp.Repository.Entities.QNote
" error. My code is generating Qclass as expected, but I can't make it work past it.

My pom file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

   <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
      <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>

   <groupId>pl.wawrzyniak</groupId>
   <artifactId>NoteApp</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>NoteApp</name>
   <description>Simple note app for CV</description>
   <properties>
      <java.version>17</java.version>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
         <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
         <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
         <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
         <version>5.0.0</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
         <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
         <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
         <version>5.0.0</version>
         <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
         <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
         <version>3.1.1</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
         <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
         <optional>true</optional>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>

   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>process</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                     <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                     <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                  </configuration>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>

         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
               <excludes>
                  <exclude>
                     <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                     <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                  </exclude>
               </excludes>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>

      </plugins>
   </build>

</project>
```

Is it something with my code? Or just problems with Spring 3 working with Querydsl?

I don't know what else i can try, sometimes my project is building and compiling till the end, but only when QClasses are not generated at all (which is to expect when there is some problem with recreating them).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my reply comes a bit late, but your post is still unanswered, so hopefully we may help someone else.

While researching exactly the same problem I found the solution here: https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/3422

=> delete the apt-maven-plugin from your pom.xml